# Logging Http Service Request Queues counters in Azure Diagnostics

Tags: iis, azure, azure-web-roles

I was reading how we can detect request queueing problem in our Azure Service irrespective of  level in our service at which it is queued.

http://blog.leansentry.com/2013/07/all-about-iis-asp-net-request-queues/

After reading the above mentioned article, I feel that setting up a monitoring on `Http Service Request Queues\CurrentQueueSize` performance counter is what I actually want. But now the question is how can I enable logging of this counter in Azure Diagnostics? I read over internet and didn't got much. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

When you create your project in Visual Studio you will see that you get a `<Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />` in your ServiceDefinition.csdef file.  This is what enables Windows Azure Diagnostics (WAD) in your deployment.

You will also see a diagnostics.wadcfg file in your Cloud Service project if you expand your Roles.  In that wadcfg you can add any perf counters you want, and you will see some examples in there that you can use as a template.  For the HTTP queue you would add something like:

```
<PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Memory\Available MBytes" sampleRate="PT3M" />
```

Once you do this then the perf counter will be in your storage account and you can query it using any standard storage tool, or one of the WAD tools such as Cerebrata, or you can configure Verbose monitoring from the management portal and then see the counter in the Monitor tab on the management portal.

Also note that Windows Azure Diagnostics 1.2 has just been released and is a good option if you haven't already enabled WAD 1.0 in your project.  For more info see http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-diagnostics/.